# How to correctly get the TransactionId with Paypal API after payment have been issued

Tags: javascript, curl, paypal, axios

I am developing a payment portal in my website, i get to place the buttons correctly and store the paymentId and PayerId i get from the api response in my database. However i am not being able to get the transactionId, which is the one that i need.

As this is my first time doing this, i didn't know i had to execute the payment with a different service from the api in order to get the transaction id (https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-XXXXXX/execute), so now i need to generate a csv with the payment info and in order to get it right i try to call the service for each payment i stored in my database and finally present the transactionID. I really don't know if this is the right approach to solve this issue, but it is what i found in the paypal page.

I tried with curl first:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-XXXXXXX/execute \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-d '{
  "payer_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}'
```

with the right info (i generated my bearer authorization, so that is not the issue), the PAYID and payerID are the ones from my database, i believe they are correct. So the first time i got this right, it was actually successful and then proceeded to implemented in my react application with Axios like this:

```
axios({
    method:'POST',
    url:"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/" + list[index].pago.paymentId + "/execute",
    responseType:'json',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    data : {
        payer_id : list[index].pago.payerId
    }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

*notice that "list" is my payments list and i have all the info inside pago. i have already checked that the info is correct.

But i received the following error :

```
{
    "name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "message":"The requested resource ID was not found",
    "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
    "debug_id":"5614cdf9e45ca"
}
```

So i thought it was maybe a problem related to my developing environment and proceeded to try with Postman, but i am getting this error:

```
{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "The request JSON is not well formed.",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "debug_id": "62277ab8964fd"
}
```

but i think this is because i couldn't make the request right. I placed the payerId within "body".

So after that i tried to use curl again just to check that everything is ok with my request... Now i also get the same error i got with Axios.

I have the feeling i screwed something after the first success and now i don't know how to make it work again.

Is this approach wrong? Is the Execute Service only to be used once? Is there any other better approach?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After payment approval, you should immediately call the execute service exactly 1 time.  It is best to use the execute_url returned from the payment creation, rather than forming the url yourself.

The response is what you use to display a message of success or failure to the payer.  The response will include a related resources sale object with a transaction ID, which you can store in your database for accounting purposes, as this is a persisted ID.  (PAYIDs are for approval only, and not persisted).

If you need to get the details of a PAYID at a later time, you can do so with a simple GET (not POST) request: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get -- however, assuming you store the results of the first execute call, for most integrations this should not be necessary, and I would recommend skipping this going forward unless you have a very good reason to be doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after a while i could solve the issue, but for sure i will change the logistic of my app by storing only the TransactionId after executing the payment.

Comment: It's good to also store the PAYID and header's PayPal-Debug-ID for debug purposes if possible -- just know that these things have no business/accounting value; the TransactionId is what will show in the PayPal.com account and reports

Comment: I never executed the payment with the api for all those payments i had, however, they were already executed by paypal. Is this the regular behavior?

Comment: You are probably calling the execute service from a javascript client.